# Modular Arithmetic: Problem with the calculation

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I am trying to solve the following:

```
99^7 (mod 123) = 54
Applying formula:
=(99 * 99^2 * 99^4) (mod 123)
= [(99 mod 123) * (99 ^2 mod 123)  * (99^4 mod 123)] mod 123
= [24* 75 * 75 * 75] mod 123 = 10,125,000 mod 123 = 82,317 * 123 
=10,124,991=9
```

With out using the formula, I am getting 54 but if I use formula, then I get 9.

Somebody please guide me.

Zulfi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your working is incorrect. The answer is indeed 54.

**Hint:** What is $99^2 \pmod{123}$?

Comment: I got it: [(99 mod 123) * (99 ^2 mod 123)  * (99^4 mod 123)] mod 123
= [(24) * (9801 mod 123) (99^4 mod 123)] mod 123 = [[24 * 84 * 84 * 84] mod 123] mod 123 = 69 mod 123 = 54. Thanks a lot. God bless you.